# How to dynamically expand indexpath row in tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uilabel

Dynamically expand the height for Tableview indexpath row depend upon the UILabel height.

I've tried many times but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

set constraint of UILabel

then write this line into viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 170;
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

and use this delegate

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```